# Import webpart in module

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-on-prem

I'm trying to deploy a custom web part to SharePoint 2013 On-Premises. I have created the web part (simple web part just an asp:label on it for testing). I also created an ASPX page (without code behind) which is deployed with a module. I can add the web part to the page from `SharePoint -> Edit page -> add web part`.

However I want to do this from my module elements file. If I do it, I got import error.

This is my aspx page main content placeholder:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Top" Title="loc:Top" />
```

And this is my module's elements.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="PagesModule" Url="Lists/Pages" List="101">
    <File Path="PagesModule\CustomerFormPage.aspx" Url="CustomerFormPage.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE">
      <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Top" WebPartOrder="0">
        <![CDATA[
        <webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="CustomerForm.WebParts.CustomerDataWebPart.CustomerDataWebPart, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">Customer</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Customer List WebPart</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
        ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this code from the MSDN page?

The type name is not correct. `$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$` is only a token.

You must replace it with the display name (strong name) of the containing project’s output assembly.

After it will look like this:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
```